# Reading query parameter in a URL with Ext JS version 4.2.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I am using *Ext JS 4.2.1* version, using model store view controller architecture. I have a scenario where server side will send URL with queryparameters. Example, say https://ascasc/asda/asdas is my page, server will hit/call this URL and they will send queryparameter as part of this URL get request.

1. I need to read the query parameter in controller, is there any function/method ext js provides or I need to use JS function `getParameterByName`?
2. Or I need to use `var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)`?
3. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.Object.fromQueryString("foo=1&bar=2"); // returns {foo: '1', bar: '2'}
Ext.Object.fromQueryString("foo=&bar=2"); // returns {foo: null, bar: '2'}
Ext.Object.fromQueryString("some%20price=%24300"); // returns {'some price': '$300'}
Ext.Object.fromQueryString("colors=red&colors=green&colors=blue"); // returns {colors: ['red', 'green', 'blue']}
```

[Doc](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.Object-method-fromQueryString)

Comment: The full answer would be: `Ext.Object.fromQueryString(window.location.search)`